# How many consecutive 0 digits are at the end of $\mathrm{K}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let K be the largest value such that $(2023!)^{2023!}$ is divisible by $42^{\mathrm{K}}$. How many consecutive 0 digits are at the end of \mathrm{K}$?

I tried to find the highest power of $42$ that divides $2023!$ Since $42 = 2 \times 3 \times 7$, we need to count the occurrences of 2, 3, and 7 in the prime factorization of $ 2023!$.

Counting the number of factors of 2 in $2023! =\left\lfloor\frac{2023{2}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor\frac{2023}{2^2}\right\rfloor \left\lfloor\frac{2023{2^3}\right\rfloor + \ldots = 1011 + 505 + 252 + \ldots$.

Counting the number of factors of 3:
$\text{Number of factors of } 3 = \left\lfloor\frac{2023}{3}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{2023}{3^2}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{2023}{3^3}\right\rfloor + \ldots.$

Counting the number of factors of 7: $\text{Number of factors of } 7 = \left\lfloor\frac{2023}{7}\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor\frac{2023}{7^2}\right\rfloor + \ldots$

Then take the minimum of these counts, pair up to get the factors of 42: $K = \min(\text{Number of factors of 2}, \text{Number of factors of 3}, \text{Number of factors of 7}) $

Calculating these counts:

1. Number of factors of 2: $ = 1011 + 505 + 252 + 126 + 63 + 31 + 15 + 7 + 3 + 1 = 2014 $
2. Number of factors of 3:$ = 674 + 224 + 74 + 24 + 8 + 2 = 1006 $
3. Number of factors of 7: $ = 289 + 41 + 5 = 335 $

Taking the minimum of these counts: $K = \min(2014, 1006, 335) = 335.$

So, the largest value of $ K $ is 335. Counting the consecutive zeros at the end of 335, is 2. Therefore, the answer is $2$. Is this right or wrong?

Comment: Hi! To avoid down-votes and close-votes, please provide us some context for this question, such as: (a) Is this homework? (b) If so, what course are you taking? (c) What specific topic are you covering at the moment? (d) What do you know that you think might be connected? (e) If you're stuck, what are you stuck on? For example, do you know what to apply, but don't know how to apply it, or do you not know what to apply? Please [edit] these facts into your original post, not as responses to this comment, as comments may be deleted without warning. ¶ E.g., this is an olympiad question, yes?

Comment: There are no zeros at the end of 355 , but there are many at the end of $K=355\times 2023!$

Comment: We know that because $2,3< 7$ there will be many more occurances of $2,3$ than of $7$ so there was never any question that you only needed to count the instance of $7$.  But now that you know $7^{355}|2023!$ we know that $7^{355\times m}|2023!^m$ and for $42^K|2023!^{2023!}$ we have $K = 355\times 2023!$.  Calculate the zeros of that.

Comment: But... why did you say the number of consecutive zeros at the end of $355$ was $2$??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have found out that $355$ is the largest value of $N$ with $42^N\mid2023!$. But the number in question is $2023!$ *to the power of itself*, and so $K=355\cdot2023!=71\cdot5\cdot2023!$. We now count how many $5$ factors are in $K$:
$$1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty\lfloor2023/5^i\rfloor=1+404+80+16+3=504$$
Since this is smaller than the number of $2$ factors in $K$ – $2014$ – the answer is $504$.